# Make new subsets for each month

Tags: pandas, datetime

I try to make subsets of each month or quarter from my data frame. I already tried some StackOverflow suggestions with the DateTime package but without success. My data frame is a Pandas data frame where the date column consists of a TimeStamp object. If someone has a suggestion that could work that would be lovely.

One of the best options from StackOverflow I already tried is:

```
date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
df['datetime'] = [datetime.strptime(dt, date_format) for dt in df['date']]
df['quarter'] = [dt.quarter for dt in df['datetime']]
dfQ1 = df[df.quarter == 1]
# for each quarter the same
```

I made timestamps of my data by the use of the following code:

```
time_stamps = []
for i in data['event_timestamp']:
time_stamps.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

You can find a picture of the head of the dataframe in the following link:
[head of the data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFmD3.png)

Comment: Hi @fzinny, welcome to the site. There are a couple of things you could do to improve your question and help people to answer: 1) paste some code samples of what you have tried already, because this will help us to understand your aims better, and 2) include your dataset in `code` format so that people can copy/paste that data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will make some alterations.